# Insecure dependency in chdir while running with -T switch when running in docker container

Tags: docker, perl, taint

I am using [`module-starter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Starter) to create a CPAN module. It automatically creates some tests

```
$ ls t/
00-load.t  manifest.t  pod-coverage.t  pod.t
```

with shebang `#!perl -T` so running the tests under taint mode. It works fine on my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 (no test failures), but when I run the same tests in Docker container with Ubuntu 20.04 and also use the module [`Alien::GSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::GSL) I get error:

```
$ perl -T -I./lib t/00-load.t 
not ok 1 - use My::Module;
#   Failed test 'use My::Module;'
#   at t/00-load.t line 10.
#     Tried to use 'My::Module'.
#     Error:  Insecure dependency in chdir while running with -T switch at /home/hakond/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/File/Find.pm line 375.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/My/Module.pm line 7.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-load.t line 10.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-load.t line 10.
```

The error can be produced more simply (in the Docker container) with:

```
$ perl -T -MAlien::GSL -e1
Insecure dependency in chdir while running with -T switch at /home/hakond/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/File/Find.pm line 375.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

the above commands runs fine (no errors) on my laptop.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the behavior in the docker container and the laptop seems to be related to `libgsl-dev` being installed on my laptop.

According to [this](https://github.com/xsawyerx/module-starter/issues/74) issue the taint mode should not be enabled by default anyway.